# Making an Asynchronous Cocoa class work in a synchronous manner

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, ios

So I'm writing a function that authenticates against an API that returns an XML document packed with things I'd like to pass. The function can make a synchronous call with NSURLConnection's `sendSynchronousRequest` method, quite easily. Yet, once this method returns, I need to instantiate an instance of NSXMLParser, initiate it with the data, let it parse, etc, etc.

What I'd like to do, is in my function (after `sendSynchronousRequest` returns), instantiate NSXMLParser, give it the data to parse, and in a single method call, get it to start the parse, and not return until the parse is over.

For example:

```
- (void) myFunction
{
 /* other code */
 NSData *returnedData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:authRequest returningResponse:&authResponse error:&authError];

 MyParserClass *parser = [[MyParserClass alloc] initWithData:returnedData];
 [parser parseData];
}
```

In the above example, `MyParserClass` is a NSXMLParser delegate, and does all the parsing in the usual, delegated fashion. `parseData` will start the parse, and not return until it is over.

In what manner should I write `parseData`? A block-approach?

EDIT: I just remembered the -parse function in NSXMLParser is synchronous. Still, i'd love to know if anyone could explain a way to do this in asynchronous classes of any sort.

Comment: And all of this is happening on a background thread, right? Synchronous networking is almost *never* the right approach in Cocoa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend writing a class that implements the `NSXMLParserDelegate` protocol (for example, `MyParserDelegate`).  When the delegate methods get called by the parser, it should build up a data structure with the information you want to extract from the XML file.  I'd call it as follows:

```
// create the delegate
MyParserDelegate *delegate = [[MyParserDelegate alloc] init];

// create the parser
NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:returnedData];
[parser setDelegate:delegate];

// parse the file
if ([parser parse])
{
    // the XML was valid and parsed without error
    // now, do something with the data you extracted
    // e.g., self.xmlData = [delegate xmlBasedDataStructureBuiltByDelegate];
}
else
{
    // the XML was invalid
    // handle the error
}
```

The functionality of `MyParserDelegate` depends entirely on what you want to extract out of the XML file.  I'd recommend reading Apple's [Event-Driven XML Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/XMLParsing.html) for more information.

Remember, if you want to use a synchronous `NSURLConnection`, you should do this on a background thread.

Comment: Thanks for the response pwc; unfortunately it doesn't answer my question though. I am concerned with the methodology of forcing an asynchronous class/API to behave in a synchronous way. My question mostly concerns blocks, since my issue is that I've built a function ('myFunction' above) that when returns somewhere else in my program, needs to have done the following in the one call; communicated with the server, parsed its response, and stored that data. The problem is, the second part is based off an asynchronous API, and does not help my one function keep its singular nature.

Comment: There's really no need to use blocks here. There's nothing asynchronous going on. In particular, NSXMLParser is not asynchronous. `[NSXMLParser parse]` returns after parsing is complete. If it were asynchronous, it would return immediately and you'd get notified on the delegate when processing was complete. It looks asynchronous because it sues a delegate, but it isn't.

Generally speaking, you can make an asynchronous process synchronous using a thread and a synchronization mechanism. You can kick off a thread to perform the async. operation and wait for the thread to complete.